# How do you call "shaft" in Spanish, meaning a vertical air passage?

Tags: traducción

What would you call **shaft** in Spanish? It is a vertical air passage, it leads below the ground level.

[image]

Suggestions: tiro, caja, canal, cubilote, mina, pozo.

Comment: I normally call it _agujero del ascensor_ or _agujero del aire_...

Comment: The definition of shaft says "an opening or passage straight down through the floors of a building", it does not mention anything about going below the ground level. Is it necessary for your purposes? If not, I think the translation is _**hueco** (del ascensor, de ventilación)_.

Comment: Quick, personal opinion (undocumented, likely localized to Chile): ducto (most generic one, a little technical), shaft, túnel (esp. if it goes underground), tubo (esp. if narrow). Most times with its specific function attached, unless obvious: _ducto de ventilación_. Tiro would work if air flows naturally, caja is sometimes used (elevator only, I think), canal may be misleading, I've never heard cubilote used, mina is _mine_, pozo is a _well_ or at least open ended at ground level.

Comment: _Tiro_ is used when the purpose is ventilation. _Caja_ is used for the elevator. _Pozo_ is just a vertical hole in the ground usually to extract water. _Mina_ is a tunnel for mineral extraction and it does not have to be vertical. So it depends on the use of the shaft it may be _tiro, pozo or caja_.

Comment: In Spain we use : *hueco del ascensor*.

Answer (score 2):

En el siguiente documento [Ascensores o elevadores](https://www.scribd.com/doc/17664512/ASCENSORES-Y-ELEVADORES) se define:

> **Caja**: es el recinto o espacio que en un edificio o estructura, se
>   destina para emplazar el ascensor. También se lo denomina **hueco** o
>   **pasadizo**.

Otro nombre utilizado en dicho documento para describir el concepto es el de **guía vertical**.